# Are Thea and Wally's hospital scenes supposed to be the same place? Or did they just reuse sets?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash, arrow

So in the hospital scene of *Arrow* 6x01, Oliver visits Rene & Thea.
The second he walked into the room of Thea it reminded me of the scene in The Flash where Barry was in the Speed Force and saw that Wally was standing in the hospital room reliving the worst moment of his live.

These rooms looked so familiar that it felt weird that both Barry and Oliver would be in that same hospital even though they live in 2 different cities.

Does anyone know if this was indeed the same hospital, or did they just film it in the same place?

Comment: Related question on Movies.SE: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49259/do-arrow-and-the-flash-share-sets

Comment: ty for that! I was looking for it here, looked in the wrong SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### *Arrow* and *The Flash* often reuse sets

As described over on [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49283/12783), *Arrow* and *The Flash* are both filmed in Vancouver and share many of the same production crew. We see almost identical locations used in both shows, such as coffee shops and characters' apartments.

Regarding the hospital, both shows reuse the hospital set on multiple occasions. Pay attention especially to the window curtains and the cabinets above the patients' head:

#### Ray Palmer — *Arrow* 3x18

[image: Ray Palmer in the hospital — Arrow 3x18]

#### Wally West — *The Flash* 3x16

[image: Wally West in the hospital — The Flash 3x16]

#### Laurel Lance — *Arrow* 4x18

[image: Laurel Lance in the hospital — Arrow 4x18]

#### Thea Queen — *Arrow* 6x01

[image]

Also, the scenes in the hospital hallways show that everybody's room is in the exact same location.

Comment: In addition, many hospital rooms DO look the same (at least in the 10 or so I've been in for various reasons), at least for the same level (ie, regular floor, intensive care, etc)

Comment: @ivanivan True, although as I recall, Wally's mother didn't die in Star City, so we have two hospitals in different cities that look identical. I'll add that in once I look it up.

Comment: Look for (older) chain hospitals IRL.   HCA (from the late 70s/early 80s) tended to use the exact blue prints to build multiple places - outsides are same, insides are same, only expansion/additions over the years has made them different.